# Fine tuning of a wrapfigure?

Tags: wrapfigure, raise

When no other solution seems available, fine tuning by hand may be helpful. Lately, I was trying to raise the content of a `wrapfigure` because it was eating the bottom margin. I had something like:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{6cm}\centering
\raisebox{20pt}{
\begin{minipage}[t]{5.8cm}
figure content
\caption
\end{minipage}}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

but it does not work. Would you have a solution? We have to make sure that the `wrapfigure` environment does not know that something is moved inside. (It makes me think of the `\mathclap` command from the `mathtools` package).

Comment: I am using XeLatex with Chinese fonts, but I believe the problem is the same in other system:

\usepackage[BoldFont...]{xeCJK}

...

...

\section{xxxxx}

 \begin{wrapfigure}{O}{0.2\textwidth}

   \begin{center}

     \includegraphics[scale=1, angle=0]{s}

   \end{center}

 \end{wrapfigure}

......(all characters become BoldFont instead of the normal font)
.....

However as I move the warpfigure to the second paragraph, i.e.
\section is separated from warpfigure, the problem disappeared.


Could anyone tell me how to correct this issue? Thanks

Comment: @JLT: If you have a question, then you should ask a new question. So it would be best to make a new post and link to this one.

Comment: Just a note to confirm Hendrik's comment, this ought to be reposted as a fresh question for you to get the best chance of it being answered.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of a `\raisebox` you can shift the content up by adding some negative vertical space before the figure content, and then compensate for that afterwards. For example compare

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{6cm}\centering
\vspace{-12pt}
\fbox{figure content}
\vspace{12pt}
\caption{Lolcats}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[3]

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{6cm}\centering
\fbox{figure content}
\caption{Lolcats}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```