# Move wrapfigure upwards to occupy space above paragraph

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure

I think, this is a similar question: [Fine tuning of a wrapfigure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3787/16144) but the answer didn't do what I hoped (actually, has no effect).

I have text wrap around image (images is aligned to right).  The image is in the beginning of paragraph. There is empty space above the text, and I would like the image to move up, to occupy some of it, while still being ran around by the text of the paragraph.

## Here's what I have:

```
Caption text

Paragraph text +---+
Paragraph text |   |
Paragraph text |   |
Paragraph text +---+
Paragraph text Para-
```

## Here's what I want:

```
               +---+
Caption text   |   |
               |   |
Paragraph text +---+
Paragraph text Parag-
raph text Paragraph
```

This is how I tried to achieve this:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}
  \centering
  \vspace{-52pt}
  \includegraphics[width=1.75in,height=1.75in]{./images/ultrasound/figure11.png}
  \vspace{50pt}
\end{wrapfigure}

\section{Bladder}
\label{sec-17}
\textbf{Views:} Transverse and sagittal, With jets in Power (5 minutes
after drinking), Prostate or Uterus underneath...
```

Answer (score 4):

Lying about the size of the image does work.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
\section{A Section}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}
  \centering
  \setbox0\hbox
    {\includegraphics[width=1.75in,height=1.75in]{example-image-duck}}%
  \ht0=50pt % change this to move it up or down
  \dp0=0pt
  \box0
\end{wrapfigure}
\blindduck[1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I'll check this when I'm back home and report.